# integral curves a circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If i need to find a first-order differential equation whose integral curves consist of all circles through the points  $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$.
Why the circles that pass through $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ have their center in the straight line $y=-x$?

Comment: I love the sincerity and the humilty, hence I have not copy to write an answer. Here you have the answer: https://www.stumblingrobot.com/2016/01/31/find-a-first-order-differential-equation-whose-integral-curves-are-all-circles-through-11-and-1-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general equation of a circle with its centre at $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is given by:

$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.
$$

Impose the condition that it passes through $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$:

$$
(1-a)^2 + (1-b)^2 = r^2,
$$
$$
(1+a)^2 + (1+b)^2 = r^2.
$$

Cancelling $r^2$ leads to:

$$
b = -a,
$$

which means that our general equation for the circle is:

$$
(x-a)^2 + (y+a)^2 = r^2.
$$

This implies that the centre of the circle lies at $(a,-a)$, which in turn tells us that all allowed centres lie along the line $y = -x$.

Further, we can write $r^2$ in terms of $a$, using e.g. the fact that it passes through $(1,1)$:

$$
r^2 = (1-a)^2 + (1+a)^2 = 2(1+a^2)
$$

So the equation of the circle becomes:

$$
(x-a)^2 + (y+a)^2 = 2(1+a^2). (*)
$$

which we can rearrange to make $a$ the subject:

$$
a = \frac{2-x^2-y^2}{2(y-x)}
$$

Now, to find the first-order differential equation whose integral curves consist of these circles we have to perform implicit differentiation on ($*$). This yields:

$$
2(x-a) + 2(y+a)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{a-x}{y+a}
$$

Put the expression for $a$ into the above and the answer follows.

Answer (score 2):

The slope should be negative reciprocal of line through points  $(1,1),(-1,-1)$ or perpendicular bisector of AB as shown, center must be on $ x+y=0$

[image]

Radius squared of variable circle =$ h^2+h^2 + (h/\sqrt 2)^2 =5 h^2 /2, $ say

The circle has equation

$$ (x-h)^2+(y+h)^2=  5 h^2/2 $$

$$ x^2+y^2- 2 x h + 2 y h =h^2 /2 \tag 1 $$

Solve for $h$ in terms of $(x,y)$

$$ h= 2(y-x) \pm \sqrt{6x^2+6y^2-8 xy} = Q(x,y) \;say\tag 2 $$

needs to be checked; either sign is acceptable as center stays on $x+y=0 $.

Differentiate wrt $x$

$$ 2x +2yy'-2h + 2 hy'=0 \tag 3 $$
or

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-Q(x,y)}{y+Q(x,y)} \tag 4 $$

so that no constant $h$ is left in the final ode.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The equation of a general circle with center $(x_0, y_0)$ is given by

$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$

Implicit differentiation will lead to

$$2(x-x_0)dx + 2(y-y_0)dy = 0$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x-x_0}{y-y_0}.$$

Now, you simply need to parameterize the center of the circles $(x_0, y_0)$. Use the equation of the circle and plug in your points that lie on the circle.